# Calling Evaluate() function of a UDF stored in an .xlam file and making it act on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions, conditional-formatting

I have written a UDF to check for and count conditionally-formatted cell colors. **Updated** Full code below.

```
Function CountCellColor(RangeToCount As Range, ColorCell As Range, _
                                           LookupType As String) As Long
'Count the number of cells in range_data that has the same color _
 as the criteria cell, including both natural and conditional formatting _
 colors. If LookpType is "cell" then it will compare cell background _
 colors, if "font" then it will compare font colors.

Dim CFFormula As String
Dim CFCell As Range
Dim CellCounter As Double
Dim CFColor As Long
Dim i, j, k As Integer

CellCounter = 0

If LookupType = "cell" Then
    CFColor = ColorCell.Interior.Color

    For i = 1 To RangeToCount.Columns.Count 'Loop thru each cell
        For j = 1 To RangeToCount.Rows.Count
            Set CFCell = RangeToCount.Cells(j, i)
            If CFCell.Interior.Color = ColorCell.Interior.Color Then 'If the natural color matches then skip right to count that cell
                GoTo CountCellColor
            Else
                For k = 1 To CFCell.FormatConditions.Count 'Otherwise check each condition format of that cell
                    If CFCell.FormatConditions(k).Interior.Color = CFColor Then 'if the conditionned color match then check the formula
                        CFFormula = CFCell.FormatConditions(k).Formula1
                        CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlA1, xlR1C1)
                        CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlR1C1, xlA1, , ActiveCell.Resize(RangeToCount.Rows.Count, RangeToCount.Columns.Count).Cells(j, 1)) 'shifts to the next cell below in the conditionally formatted column
                        If Evaluate(CFFormula) = True Then  'if the formula evaluates to true then count that cell. Needs reference to ActiveCell cuz the macro is stored in a different file
CountCellColor:
                            CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

ElseIf LookupType = "font" Then
    CFColor = ColorCell.Font.Color

    For i = 1 To RangeToCount.Columns.Count 'Loop thru each cell
        For j = 1 To RangeToCount.Rows.Count
            Set CFCell = RangeToCount.Cells(j, i)
            If CFCell.Font.Color = ColorCell.Font.Color Then 'If the natural color matches then skip right to count that cell
                GoTo CountFontColor
            Else
                For k = 1 To CFCell.FormatConditions.Count 'Otherwise check each condition format of that cell
                    If CFCell.FormatConditions(k).Font.Color = CFColor Then 'if the conditionned color match then check the formula
                        CFFormula = CFCell.FormatConditions(k).Formula1
                        CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlA1, xlR1C1)
                        CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlR1C1, xlA1, , ActiveCell.Resize(RangeToCount.Rows.Count, RangeToCount.Columns.Count).Cells(j, 1)) 'shifts to the next cell below in the conditionally formatted column
                        If Evaluate(CFFormula) = True Then 'if the formula evaluates to true the count that cell
CountFontColor:
                            CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                Next k
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

Else
    CountCellColor = -1
    Exit Function
End If

CountCellColor = CellCounter

End Function
```

I have tested that this works well for these cases:

1. UDF is stored in file A, UDF is called in file A sheet 1, target
   range is in file A sheet 1
2. UDF is stored in file A, UDF is called in file A sheet 1, target range is in file A sheet 2
3. UDF is stored in loaded .xlam file, UDF is called in file A sheet 1, target range is also in file A sheet 1 (pic 1)

[image: screenshot]

This 1 case below does not work
1. *UDF is stored in loaded .xlam file, UDF is called in file A sheet 1, target range is in file A sheet 2*

Right now, the UDF does not return any errors, but it just evaluates the Evaluate(CFFormula) line as FALSE and does not increment the count.
[image: screenshot]

I called it on a structured table like this:

```
=CountCellColor(LDL1P1[EDL1 Need Trans],$I$5,"cell")
```

The formula to be evaluated is simply A2="aaa". So it really depends where this evaluate() function executes. It should be done in the same sheet as RangeToCount for this to work.

Comment: It seems that `Evaluate(CFFormula)` it is not working properly (maybe length?) Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate

Comment: The Evaluate formula works well for the first 3 cases. In the last case, it is probably referring to the wrong workbook. So I need Evaluate() to be called in reference to the sheet where the RangeToCount is found.

Comment: With no more information, it is impossible to know how it is working... Show us one sample of "CFFormula"

Comment: I suspect that is not a proper UDF. Seems to call on global variables (standard call out to `Option Explicit`!) and may even try to modify cells (`ConvertFormula`: Converts cell references in a formula). So it will always return an error, regardless of how technically correct the code is.

Comment: I updated the OP guys. Please read again. Thanks!
@AJD this UDF works fine in the 3 cases I mentioned.

Comment: Calling `Evaluate` (on it's own) is a shortcut to `Application.Evaluate`, which is called in the context of the Active Sheet.  Try the sheet scooped version, ie `CFCell.Worksheet.Evaluate(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I think Evaluate() will always run on the activesheet. So if you need it to run on another sheet, you need to specify so.

```
RangeToCount.Parent.Evaluate(CFFormula)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues compounding your problems here

1. `Evaluate` (on it's own) is a shortcut to Application.Evaluate, which is called in the context of the Active Sheet. Use the sheet scooped version.
2. Your code to offset the CF formula using `ConvertFormula` doesn't work in all cases.  It's also tied to the Active Sheet, and doesn't work at all if the conditional formatted range is not aligned with the cell containing the `CountCellColor` formula.
3. While not your issue, using `GoTo` like that is really bad practice
4. Counting of Natural colored cells, should only be counted if color has not been changed by CF'g
5. `RangeToCount` might contains multiple different CF regions, so need to account for that
6. This code works for Expression type CF'g only, so test for that
7. Other minor opportunities for improvement (see code below)

Your code, refactoed

```
Function CountCellColor( _
  RangeToCount As Range, _
  ColorCell As Range, _
  LookupType As String) As Long
'Count the number of cells in range_data that has the same color _
 as the criteria cell, including both natural and conditional formatting _
 colors. If LookpType is "cell" then it will compare cell background _
 colors, if "font" then it will compare font colors.

 'Only counts Natural colored cells, if they are not colored by CF'g

    Dim CFFormula As String
    Dim CFCell As Range
    Dim CellCounter As Long '<~~~ you are counting, so use an int type
    Dim CFColor As Long
    Dim Rng As Range, cl As Range
    Dim CountedCell As Boolean
    Dim FC As FormatCondition

    CellCounter = 0

    If StrComp(LookupType, "cell", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then '<~~~ case insensitive
        CFColor = ColorCell.Interior.Color

        For Each CFCell In RangeToCount.Cells  '<~~~ Loop thru each cell
            CountedCell = False
            For Each FC In CFCell.FormatConditions   'check each conditional format of that cell
                If FC.Type = xlExpression Then
                    'shifts to the next cell below in the conditionally formatted column.
                    'Must be in the context of the passed range and its worksheet
                    Set Rng = FC.AppliesTo.Cells(1, 1)
                    CFFormula = FC.Formula1
                    CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlA1, xlR1C1, False, Rng)
                    CFFormula = Application.ConvertFormula(CFFormula, xlR1C1, xlA1, False, CFCell)

                    If RangeToCount.Worksheet.Evaluate(CFFormula) = True Then
                    'if the formula evaluates to true then consider that cell.
                        CountedCell = True
                        If FC.Interior.Color = CFColor Then
                        'if the conditionned color match then count
                            CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            ' Only count base color cells that are not colored by CF
            If Not CountedCell Then
                If CFCell.Interior.Color = CFColor Then
                    CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next

    ElseIf StrComp(LookupType, "font", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        ' similar

    Else
        CountCellColor = -1
    End If

    CountCellColor = CellCounter

End Function
```

---

That said, there is an easier way - if you have a late enough version of Excel that supports `DisplayFormat` (Excel 2010 or later)

```
Function CountCellColor2( _
  RangeToCount As Range, _
  ColorCell As Range, _
  LookupType As String) As Long

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim MatchColor As Long
    Dim CellCounter As Long

    If StrComp(LookupType, "cell", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        MatchColor = ColorCell.Interior.Color
        For Each cl In RangeToCount.Cells
            If cl.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = MatchColor Then
                CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    ElseIf StrComp(LookupType, "font", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        MatchColor = ColorCell.Font.Color
        For Each cl In RangeToCount.Cells
            If cl.DisplayFormat.Font.Color = MatchColor Then
                CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
            End If
        Next
    End If
    CountCellColor2 = CellCounter
End Function
```